# How does g++ align memory to make sure the alignment starts at the beginning of a cacheline?

Tags: c++, caching, memory, memory-management, g++

I read that in g++ we can do :

```
struct foo {
    int a, b, c;
} __attribute__((__aligned__(64)));
```

so that the struct foo is of size 64 --- which is normally the size of a cache line. when we need to access this cache line, cpu can load foo in one go.

Does this mean that CPU can load foo from L2 at any memory address --- not necessarily a round number of 64?

imaging that foo 's address in memory is something like 0xFFFF3, does CPU need to read TWO cache lines to load foo?

Can anybody clarify this for me?

PS: I am using g++ 6.2 on CentOS 64bit

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Alignment

Comment: I'm not an expert on details of the newest C++ language standard, but in the past, most compilers allowed you some control over the _alignment requirements_ of different data types.  The reason is, there's a tradeoff on some architectures (e.g., x86):  Pack structures more tightly, and your program runs slower, but your data takes up less space. That's a decision that the application developer should be allowed to make.

Comment: @jameslarge why pack structures more tightly and program runs slower? I had thought the opposite: packed structures cause less cache miss so the program runs faster.

Comment: A 64-bit x86-64 operand can lie on any byte address, but the CPU will have to perform _two_ cache operations to fetch/store it if the address is not a multiple of 8.  If you mix fields of different sizes in a struct, then depending on compile options, the compiler may need to use _padding_ (unused space in the struct) to make every field line up on its preferred boundary.  If you use a compiler option that means, "no padding," then you will get a smaller struct, but some fields can only be accessed with a double fetch/store.  For some architectures, "no padding" is not even an option.

Answer (score 0):

Aligned is related with where start the address of the structure in memory. If the size of your structure is less or equals to 64 bytes, then you are right and your structure will fit in one line cache, but if the structure is bigger than 64 bytes that is always false.

Aligned is only related with where will start a local or global variable of that type. When you are writing algorithms that try to explode the power of the processor is good optimise the data access aligned to 64 bytes so that you can process 64 continuous bytes without any cache fault. By the way the optimiser of the compiler create more optimal code when data are aligned to 64 bytes.

A quick test is to create a small program, and generate the assembler code with aligned and without aligned, and compare the assembler that you get. (A small loop that access local vectors for example), enabling the optimiser (-O2 or -O3).

PS: When using the heap, you can do it by yourself allocating

```
struct foo *myFoo = (malloc(size(struct foo)+15) + 15) & (~ 0x0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two questions masked as one. I will try to answer them.

First, alignment question. Generally speaking, C++ compiler knows nothing (or pretends to know nothing) of the cache lines and such. Instead, it simply makes sure that all objects of this type are aligned to 64 byte boundaries (provided they are natively smaller or equal in size to 64). This is where compiler job is done.

Now, we need to focus on CPU behavior. Since cache line size is 64 bytes, when the object is aligned on 64 byte boundary, we are certain that the whole object is going to be in the cache when we load it. As a result, access to object members is guaranteed to be served by L1 cache rather than more expensive ways (L2, for example).

Since L2 is a much bigger cache, there is no reason to try to align code to adhere to L2 boundaries.

Comment: does this mean, if I do "foo* p = new foo();", p will always points to a 'round' memory address which is a multiplier of 64?

Comment: @user152503 not in pre-C++17. In C++17, it can be achieved by using align argument to `operator new`